# Save time with another time zone diiferent from server time zone

Tags: java, date, time, timezone

I chose a time for example I have entered Thu Jan 01 16:00:00 WET 1970 and also a timezone for example GMT+1:00. I mean that I want to record this date with this time zone (16:00 already in gmt+1). But after saving the model the value is getting saved as Thu Jan 01 15:00:00 WET 1970 in the database.

The server is in Africa/Casablanca timezone.

I tried to convert this date into String with time zone what I want and it shows me the correct time but when I try to convert this string to Date I still receive the time with one hour less.

```
      DisplayedTimeZone displayedTimeZone = configuration.getDisplayedTimeZone();
    if(displayedTimeZone != null){
        Date orderCuttOffTime = configuration.getCutOffTime(); // Thu Jan 01 15:00:00 WET 1970
        if(orderCuttOffTime != null){
          SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
          sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(displayedTimeZone.getCode()));
          String closingTime = sdf.format(orderCuttOffTime); // 1970-01-01 16:00:00 +0100
          try {
                configuration.setCutOffTime(dateFormat.parse(cuttOffTime)); // returns again Thu Jan 01 15:00:00 WET 1970 and not 16:00:00
          }catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Even the cuttofftime contains the time Thu `1970-01-01 16:00:00 +0100` that I want to save in database dateFormat.parse(cuttOffTime) returns the value `Thu Jan 01 15:00:00 WET 1970`

I want during the parse to send me a date with the same time which is in the string

Answer (score 1):

A `java.util.Date` object simply represents an instant on the timeline — a wrapper around the number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT). Since it does not hold any timezone information, its **[`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString--)** function applies the JVM's timezone to return a `String` in the format, `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`, derived from this ***milliseconds*** value. To get the `String` representation of the `java.util.Date` object in a different format and timezone, you need to use `SimpleDateFormat` with the desired format and the applicable timezone e.g.

```
Date date = new Date();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
String strDateNewYork = sdf.format(date);

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
String strDateUtc = sdf.format(date);
```

## *java.time*

With the release of Java SE 8 in March 2014, the outdated and error-prone legacy Date-Time API (`java.util` Date-Time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` etc.) was supplanted by `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API<sup>*</sup>. The [following table](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) depicts the mapping of ANSI SQL types with `java.time` types:

| ANSI SQL | Java SE 8 |
| --- | --- |
| DATE | LocalDate |
| TIME | LocalTime |
| TIMESTAMP | LocalDateTime |
| TIME WITH TIMEZONE | OffsetTime |
| TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE | OffsetDateTime |

Note that `ZonedDateTime` and `Instant` are not supported by any JDBC driver whereas some drivers e.g. PostgreSQL also do not support `OffsetTime` / `TIME [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ]`.

### How to use it in JDBC?

Given below is a sample code to insert the current `OffsetDateTime` in UTC, into `columnfoo` (which is of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` type):

```
OffsetDateTime odt = Instant.now().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (columnfoo) VALUES (?)");
st.setObject(1, odt);
st.executeUpdate();
st.close();
```

Given below is a sample code to retrieve a `OffsetDateTime` from `columnfoo`:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE <some condition>");
while (rs.next()) {
    // Assuming the column index of columnfoo is 1
    OffsetDateTime odt = rs.getObject(1, OffsetDateTime.class));
    System.out.println(odt);
}
rs.close();
st.close();
```

**Just in case you need to convert `odt` to represent the date-time in your timezone:**

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Africa/Casablanca"));
System.out.println(zdt); // With timezone and timezone offset
System.out.println(zdt.toOffsetDateTime()); // With timezone offset
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Given that `cutOffTime` is a [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), there is nothing you can do, since `Date` doesn't have a time zone and is always stored in UTC.

The time zone `WET` that you see is simply the default rendering of the `Date` value.

If you want to save a time with time zone and without date, use the Java 8+ [`OffsetTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetTime.html) class instead of `Date`.